# Prevent Applications from changing workspace

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

Is it possible to prevent applications from auto-switching workspace.
On my current setup my IDE always jumps to my current workspace when it catches
a break point. This is messing my arrangement. I could accept auto switching workspace on event but applications should stay in place.

Comment: You might like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/666357/how-can-i-lock-an-application-and-all-its-new-windows-into-a-specific-workspac/666718#666718

Comment: P.S. I voted as a dupe, not as "unclear" ^, since I pretty much get what your intention is.

Comment: Thanks just had a short look at it right now. But it seems this could do what i want. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean by "prevent applications from changing workspace" that Ubuntu should prevent the IDE running on workspace x to switch to this workspace while debugging an application on workspace y when hitting a breakpoint then:

*No, that's not possible, this is by design...*

Comment: Thank you, wasn't sure on the translation. As i understand there is still a slight difference between viewport and workspace(what i meant) but still, considering the comment of Jacob Vlijm also workspaces do not support (per default) the behavior i would like to have.

Comment: Me neither: but it got your question reopened and you're an 8-rep user already!  **;-)**